# Remote telnet to reboot a modem not working

Tags: shell, scripting, telnet

I have a modem which I need to reboot from a router. A modem accepts only telnet and has a Web GUI. If I telnet from the router manually, I can reboot the modem with no problem at all.

But when I try to issue following at the router:

```
(sleep 1; echo usr; sleep 1; echo pwd; sleep 5; echo reboot; ) | telnet 192.168.0.1
```

it will log me in, show a prompt `#` at the router, but it will never do the third command. What am I doing wrong?

For test purposes:

1. I tried using `ls` instad of reboot
2. I tried varying the `sleep` lengths
3. I tried from a Raspberry Pi instead of from a router

but I can never get a modem to accept and/or execute any command after a login using telnet this way.

I have no `expect` available.  I would prefer to solve it using router's `sh` script as it already does several things there.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work, but to get rid of the `sleep` stuff (which is unreliable guesswork at best), you can e.g. use `expect` and send off the next command at the next prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I was too quick. It works with:

```
(sleep 1; echo usr; sleep 1; echo pwd; sleep 1; echo ls; sleep 1; ) | telnet 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Is this an answer or an update to your question? If it's your own answer please accept it (with the tick mark) so we know it's resolved. If it's an update to your question please [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/315868/edit) instead, and delete this non-answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a trailing `sleep` to allow the router time to action the `reboot` command before the `telnet` session is closed. I'd suggest two seconds but you may need to tweak this for your situation.

Try this

```
( s(){sleep "${1:-1}";}; s; echo usr; s; echo pwd; s; echo reboot; s 2 ) | telnet 192.168.0.1
```